# How to catch a Python error?

Tags: python, try-except

I want a way I can catch error input from the user. I found Pythons try/except method.

I have this so far:

```
def take_a_guess(self):
    random_card_rank = random.choice(list(self.card.rank.keys()))
    random_card_suit = random.choice(self.card.suit)
    print(random_card_rank)
    print(random_card_suit)
    rank_guess, suit_guess = input('Guess the card: ').split()
    guesses = 3

    while guesses != 0:
        # try:
            if int(rank_guess) == random_card_rank and suit_guess.rstrip() == random_card_suit:
                print('Wow, well done you got it in one')
                guesses -= 3
            else:
                print('Nah')
                return False
            return True
        # except ValueError:
        #     print('You cant do that! Try again...')
```

but if I type in 1 thing to the input, it says `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` I get why but I thought that the `except` would catch this and tell me I cannot do this??

Comment: Where is the `input` you speak of?

Comment: updated the code @Idos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to surround the **entire** relevant piece of code in your `try` in order to `catch` the relevant error. Your error stems from this line:

```
rank_guess, suit_guess = input('Guess the card: ').split()
```

Which is not in your `try` block at all.
You should add your `try` anywhere before that line:

```
def take_a_guess(self):

    random_card_rank = random.choice(list(self.card.rank.keys()))
    random_card_suit = random.choice(self.card.suit)
    print(random_card_rank)
    print(random_card_suit)

    # try should be here at the very least (or higher)
    rank_guess, suit_guess = input('Guess the card: ').split()

    # catch could be here and it would catch the error as expected

    guesses = 3
    while guesses != 0:
        # try should not be here
            if int(rank_guess) == random_card_rank and suit_guess.rstrip() == random_card_suit:
                print('Wow, well done you got it in one')
                guesses -= 3
            else:
                print('Nah')
                return False
            return True
        # except ValueError:
        #     print('You cant do that! Try again...')
```

In order to keep looping if the error is raised you can extract that line into the `while` like so:

```
def take_a_guess(self):

    random_card_rank = random.choice(list(self.card.rank.keys()))
    random_card_suit = random.choice(self.card.suit)
    print(random_card_rank)
    print(random_card_suit)

    guesses = 3
    while guesses != 0:
        try:
            rank_guess, suit_guess = input('Guess the card: ').split()
        except ValueError:
            print('You cant do that! Try again...')
            continue

            if int(rank_guess) == random_card_rank and suit_guess.rstrip() == random_card_suit:
                print('Wow, well done you got it in one')
                guesses -= 3
            else:
                print('Nah')
                return False
            return True
```

Comment: ok that is almost perfect, the only problem is instead of trying again, it just exits. i cant work out how to indent it so it stays in the while loop until it gets a correct input..

Comment: @NewUser123 why not just add that line to the `while` loop?

Comment: I have edited my answer to give you the general idea

Answer (score 0):

What you want to try/catch is the

```
rank_guess, suit_guess = input('Guess the card: ').split()
```

You're trying to split something that you don't know yet.

Have you tried it?